# Can i ignore code from an Event using lambda expression

Tags: c#, wpf, events

There is the Context:

```
Class A{
  public void mymethod(){
    MyWindow window = new MyWindow();
    window.Show();
  }
}
```

```
public partial class MyWindow: Window
{
   private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
   {
     //Some Code Here
   }

}
```

Can i perform in *MyMethod* : `MyWindow.Closing -= (_,__) => {};`  to ignore the code write in *Window_Closing* ?

Comment: why not try it out?

Comment: why do you have an event-handler you do not want to execute?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I couldn't do the test because I didn't have a development environment available when I asked the question. (asked from my phone)

Comment: @HimBromBeere And for a very specific case, because of an exception that cannot be processed internally in MyWindow, the data saved using the events should not be saved in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible.
Events are multicast delegates, which means that an event holds a collection of callbacks that's why the syntax `+=` and `-=` and not just `=`.
Events in C# are compiled on a different way that they 'seem to be' on code. Externally to the class exposing the event the only operations that can be done are adding and removing callbacks. Inside the class declaring the event other actions are available (invoke the event callbacks, access the list of registrations...) but that's another topic.

To remove an already added callback you need to have a reference to that specific callback which in your case is `MyWindow.Window_Closing` for each `MyWindow` instance, the method is for now private so you cannot.
If `MyWindow.Window_Closing` was public you could do:

```
window.Closing -= window.Window_Closing
```

But that only would work for that callback, if other classes were also subscribed to the event they would be notified, you cannot access all callbacks from outside the class declaring the event.